# How to interlace ouput of nodes two content types in views

Tags: 7, views

I have nodes of two different content types and want to output them interlacing in a view. So nodes of type A are on odd places and nodes of type B on even ones.

Is there a straight-forward way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a view that outputs the two node types and then use `hook_views_pre_render()` to sort, shuffle, or arrange the `$view->result` array any way you wanted.  Then when it is rendered in the next steps, it would be printed however you wanted.  You would hook into this like:

```
function YOURMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  if ($view->name=='thisistheviewyouarelookingfor') {

    // do whatever you want with $view->result[]

  }

}
```

MORE INFO:  `$view->result[]` is an array of "rows" basically, eg `$view->result[0]` contains all the raw data that makes up the first row, `$view->result[1]` is the second, etc.

Comment: Great! I knew it must be simple :)